# What tools exist in Perl 5 for automating external programs?

Tags: perl, automation

Besides modules that are specific to a given service (like [ClearCase::Proc::ClearTool](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ClearCase-Tools/lib/ClearCase/Proc/ClearTool.pm)), what modules or built-in functions exist to automate external programs?

Answer (score 10):

For programs expecting input on `STDIN` and output on `STDOUT` or `STDERR` there is:

- The [`open` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- [`IPC::Open2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html)
- [`IPC::Open3`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html)

For programs expecting interactive input there is [`Expect`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect/Expect.pod).

For web applications there is:

- [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)
- [`WWW::Scripter`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Scripter/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod)
- [`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-WWW-Selenium/util/create_www_selenium.pl)
- [`WWW::HtmlUnit`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-HtmlUnit/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm)

For generic TCP and UDP servers there is [`IO::Socket`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html).

For web services that expect SOAP there is:

- [`SOAP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SOAP-Lite/lib/SOAP/Lite.pm)
- [`XML::Compile::SOAP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-SOAP-2.15/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP.pod)

For XML-RPC there is [`RPC::XML`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RPC-XML/lib/RPC/XML.pm).

For MS Windows applications there is [`Win32::GuiTest`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GuiTest/lib/Win32/GuiTest.pm).

For X Windows applications there is [`X11::GUITest`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/X11-GUITest/GUITest.pm).

For applications that support DBus there is [`Net::DBus`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-DBus/lib/Net/DBus.pm).

For OS X programs that support Applescript there is [`Mac::Glue`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mac-Glue/Glue.pm).

Comment: For Windows apps, there is Win32::GuiTest

Comment: @runrig Thanks, I have added it and a link to it to the list.

Comment: more SOAP: XML::Compile::SOAP;  more GUI automation: X11::GUITest;  for XML-RPC: RPC::XML;  for application automation: Net::DBus, Mac::Glue

Comment: for Windows applications that have OLE Automation interfaces (COM), there is Win32::OLE.

Comment: should the basic ones like system and qx{} be added?